# Naive question - Is Magnetic generator (like this) not a 'perpetual motion machine'?

Tags: electromagnetism, perpetual-motion

Perhaps a question that is too naive to be on Physics.SE but I let the experts here decide (and downvote at will), but there seem to a certain company that claims to have created what it calls a "magnetic generator" where, if the machine is powered externally long enough (which is in seconds or minutes) allowing an electro-magnetic contraption to reach a certain RPM, it can start producing enough electricity to keep turning the contraption, without the aid of the external power while generating surplus electricity. This sounds like perpetual motion machine, yet a bit "snake oilish". The website of this company is done very professionally, they have some slick youtube vidoes -- but scamsters can and do pull impressive illusions off. Is there plausible physics behind this setup ?

Please note that I have no interest in the company or the product, but quite interested to know if there is some real physics behind it.

Here's a [link](https://infinitysav.com/magneticgenerator/) that describes the product.

Comment: Odds it is not a scam are the same as the odds of me flying to the moon by flapping my arms.

Comment: Buy one, test it and report back.

Comment: Do these things power the homes the company owners live in ? :-)  Guess the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's garbage. Just another perpetual motion/free energy scam.

Comment: Thanks Niels. It is then a pretty elaborate scam. While I don't have spare cash to buy it, I have to admit that I might have given it a thought if I had some... after checking the answers here :-).

Comment: Icarus, a slight variant on this same basic scam fooled the Austrian government, which contracted with the scammer to have magnetic free energy generators built and delivered for installation in their power grid. None of the investment strategists working for the government saw what any engineer or physicist would have seen instantly: that it was all garbage. So don't feel too badly.